# how to manage large serialized data object in .net

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, serialization, memory

I have large (20-30 MB) serialized data object(data serialized from excel) as input for my .net application.  Whenever user request through webservice, I need to process output based on user input as well as the data from serialized object.

**Which is the effective way to store these object in .net application (cache/session/application object)?**  Because these serialized data object changes 3 or 4 times in a year.  I don't want to load these serialized object data into memory each time when user request send to webserivce.

*Also I would like to know how these objects can be stored in the memory and disk  so that it will not take much memory space as well as disk space.*

Comment: 20-30mb is alot to be consuming via a web service call.

Comment: 20-30 mb data is not passing to client side, this data is needed for calculation for webservice

Answer (score 1):

Use *static* variable to store serialized object. As you mentioned the serialized object has a global scope, so don't store in session as it is *user/session*. Also we often store items in cache that are mostly used, and updated in regular intervals but as you mentioned it will be updated 3-4 times in a year, so Cache is not a good candidate here in IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand your needs, but I suppose you should change your application architecture and store data as entries rather than serializing it to 20Mb object. Serializing of 20mb object is a bad idea.

Use [MS SQL Server Compact](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fsqlserver%2F2008%2Fen%2Fus%2Fcompact.aspx&rct=j&q=sql%20server%20compact&ei=0UZjTdLwBoKEOp6ysb8N&usg=AFQjCNE1yX6LmbsUJLIupIsXY_LEnmPLiQ&sig2=ZKMKIHG2GHLcSg2YUDqQ7w&cad=rja), it's free and lightweight in-proc database from MS, assemblies take about 1Mb of disk space. I used it even for Windows Service Application, and it behaves itself amazingly fast and reliable.